# Dynamic linq OrderBy isn't working for me

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, odata

I am having trouble dynamically specifying the column and direction to sort on.
I currently have the following code:

```
if (sort != "OrderID")
{
    if (sort == "EmployeeName")
    {
        sort = "Employee.FirstName"; //sort by Employee FirstName
    }
    else
    {
        sort = "Customer." + sort; //Customer.CompanyName sort
    }
}

var sortCriteria = string.Format("{0} {1}", sort, sortDir);
var res1 = nwd.Orders //response
    .OrderBy(o => sort+" "+sortDir)
    .ThenBy(o => o.OrderID)
    .Skip((page - 1) * rowsPerPage)
    .Take(rowsPerPage)
    .Select(o => new
    {
        o.OrderID,
        o.Customer.CompanyName,
        o.Customer.ContactName,
        o.Employee.FirstName,
        o.Employee.LastName,
        o.Order_Details
    }).ToList();
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You have a typo on string.format...

Comment: Also, are you sure that `.OrderBy(o => sort+" "+sortDir)` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
var res1 = nwd.Orders //response

IOrderedQueryable<Orders> result;

if (sort != "OrderID")
{
    if (sort == "EmployeeName")
    {
        result = res1.OrderBy(o => o.Employee.FirstName);
    }
    else
    {
        result= res1.OrderBy(o => o.Customer.CompanyName);
    }
}

result = result.ThenBy(o => o.OrderID)
             .Skip((page - 1) * rowsPerPage)
             .Take(rowsPerPage)
             .Select(o => new
             {
                 o.OrderID,
                 o.Customer.CompanyName,
                 o.Customer.ContactName,
                 o.Employee.FirstName,
                 o.Employee.LastName,
                 o.Order_Details
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: I get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<LINQPad.User.Order>' to 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery<LINQPad.User.Order>'" when I try this

Comment: what is your context and how does nwd relate to the context?

Comment: var nwd = new OdataServiceReference.NorthwindEntities(new Uri("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/"));

Comment: i have made some changes after investigating how LINQPad queries work. See if this helps?

Comment: Ok, so that says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<LINQPad.User.Order>'."

Comment: This ended up working with a little bit of fiddling. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a working example with a dummy class:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list_people = new List<Person> {
              new Person() {Age = 4, Name = "yo"}, 
              new Person() {Age = 5, Name = "a"}  
        };

        var dynamic_propretry = typeof (Person).GetProperty("Name");
        var sorted = list_people.OrderBy(person => dynamic_propretry.GetValue(person, null));

        foreach (var person in sorted)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(person);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Person{

 public int Age { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + ":" + Age;
    }
}
```

So, all you have to do is store the property you want in a string, and just use that string where I used `"Name"`. It should work.

Comment: I tried to use my sort criteria variable like so 
.OrderBy(o => sortCriteria), but that doesn't work either. You're saying it should be something like .OrderBy(o => o.OrderID) right? How do I do that dynamically?

Comment: yep, that's what i'm saying. if it's a property, you can get it using reflection, other than that, a switch might serve you, depending on how many options you have, and how lenient you are on this approach :)

Comment: Alright, is there a was to make a switch for only the OrderBy? (Sorry if that's a stupid question)

Comment: Hmmmm after casting those orders to lists it now gives a NullReferenceException on the line that reads '.Select(o => new'

Comment: look at the updated answer. Much better and working example. You'll simply have to use your objects / sorting and you're set.

Comment: Thanks so much for that! I'm still getting an error though... I get the expression null.getGetValue([10007], null) is not supported.

Comment: sounds like you're having a null in there ... :)

Comment: Yep, I managed to fix that quite easily, but it still threw OrderID.getGetValue([10007], null) is not supported... I managed to get failedprogramming's solution working, but it is quite a lot less elegant.